# Tcolorbox and tikz package for colored page

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, boxes, tcolorbox

Bonjour. How to code these two pages in latex using tikz package.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! The answer to your question is: with some amount of skill and patience. None of the above is particularly difficult but the sheer multitude of little things to be done kills probably the motivation in many of us to answer. So I recommend that you try yourself and report on where you get stuck.

Comment: I’ve learn yesterday in this site how to do boxes with tips and I’ve done something in my own. But I don’t really know where to start with this.

Comment: I edited the post. Firstly I just want to know how to do this header

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is `sesamanuel` class

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{sesamanuel}

\begin{document}

\themaF
\chapter{title}

\end{document}
```

[image]